# Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : object 'Juice_practice' not found when running binary logistic regression in r

Tags: r, binary, regression, logistic-regression

I am trying to run a binary logistic regression, here is my code:

```
dataTest <- read.csv("location.csv")
dataTest
dataTest<- as.factor(dataTest$Juice_practice)

str(dataTest)
head(dataTest)
summary(dataTest)

logit_model <- glm(Juice_practice ~ Age + Gender + Education,
                   family = binomial, data = dataTest)`
Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : 
  object 'Juice_practice' not found
```

Initially I was getting this error message

```
Error in eval(family$initialize) : y values must be 0 <= y <= 1
```

Then I did this:

`dataTest<- as.factor(dataTest$Juice_practice)`

When I check `str(dataTest)`, it shows this
`Factor w/ 2 levels "No","Yes": 2 2 1 2 2 2 1 2 1 1 ...`

When I check `head(dataTest)` it shows this;
`[1] Yes Yes No  Yes Yes Yes Levels: No Yes`

I don't know what happened to the columns after setting Juice_practice as a factor. I do not know how to address this data structure problem.

Comment: You are overwriting `dataTest` so that it is no longer a data.frame, it is a vector made from a single column. Instead of overwriting the entire data.frame, assign to just the column that you want to make into a factor.

Comment: Totally lost, i thought what i did was to turn column Juice_practice to a factor. How do I assign Juice_practice column i want to a factor without overwriting dataTest?

Comment: Try `dataTest$Juice_practice<- as.factor(dataTest$Juice_practice)` or `dataTest <- transform(dataTest, Juice_practice=as.factor(Juice_practice))` instead

Comment: Thanks, this worked dataTest$Juice_practice<- as.factor(dataTest$Juice_practice)